# Spring config server not starting with keystore

Tags: spring, encryption, config, keystore

trying to boot spring cloud config server with a keystore but am getting the following on startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionBootstrapConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'textEncryptor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$RsaEncryptionConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor]: Factory method 'textEncryptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'textEncryptor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$RsaEncryptionConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor]: Factory method 'textEncryptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException    

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.encrypt.EncryptorFactory.create(EncryptorFactory.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
```

The following options are used to start the component:

```
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=http://mygit.com/alexander.lovett/service-discovery-demo.git
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=Software/config
--spring.rabbitmq.host=spring-bus
--management.security.enabled=false
--encrypt.keystore.location=file://C:/Users/607567487/BTTV/workspace/service-discovery-demo/Software/config-serverserver.jks
--encrypt.keystore.secret=changeme
--encrypt.keystore.password=letmein
--encrypt.keystore.alias=mytestkey
```

I've tried the location as `file://C:/.../server.jks` `file:C:/.../server.jks` and even put the jks on the classpath and tried `classpath:server.jks`

But still get the same error regardless.

My dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix...

the properties should be `encrypt.key-store.*` not `encrypt.keystore.*`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but a different cause. Here is a short [description](http://itzap.com/factory-method-textencryptor-threw-exception/). In a nutshell, the problem was caused by `ENCRYPT_KEY` environment variable that triggered `textEncryptor` bean autoconfig with malformed `KeyProperties`. Spring failed to populate `KeyProperties` from the environment variable `ENCRYPT_KEY` causing `NullPointerException`. If encryption key is provided as system property `-Dencrypt.key=123` then spring will have no problems configuring `textEncryptor` bean.